# What is the underlying algorithm to simplify sums of reciprocals of polynomials?

Tags: polynomials, summation, implementation-details

Flipping through [Wolfram's blog entry on Leibniz](http://blog.stephenwolfram.com/2013/05/dropping-in-on-gottfried-leibniz/), W noted Huygens' interview test for the young Leibniz, namely to determine:

$$\sum_{n\ge2} \frac{1}{{n \choose 2}}$$

It's one thing to do this by hand (hint: partial fractions $\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}$ then telescope). But [Wolfram's link to Wolfram Alpha to solve it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%202%2F(n(n-1))), seems to do so symbolically (for god's sake, solve it by hand first!). I am curious, what is the *general* algorithm to solve these kinds of sums of reciprocals symbolically?

Is there an algorithm to specifically address sums of reciprocals of binomials? Does the A=B/hypergeometric summation method apply here? Or is it a table look up or what? Or is the algorithm as simple as 'just do partial fractions' (but doesn't that violate summation rules for alternating infinite sums?)?

[MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html) has some solutions, and some involve hypergeometrics, but there's no hint of an algorithm for these.

Comment: The documentation of `Sum[]` notes a number of supported `Method`s, including `"RationalFunction"`, which seems to be the one being used in this case.

Comment: @J.M. `RationalFunction` presumably uses many methods (like A=B). I'd like to know which submethod is used for the example.

Comment: Presumably it's using a method specialized for rational functions; neither `"HypergeometricTermGosper"` nor `"HypergeometricTermZeilberger"` work. But, `"HypergeometricTermPFQ"` works. Hmm...

Answer (score 4):

[`Trace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) the command with the option `TraceInternal -> True`.  It's not *very* long.  You'll come across the following, which computes the result:

```
Trace[
 Sum`SumParserDump`sumParserEvaluate[2/((-1 + n) n), {{n, 2, ∞}}, {}],
 TraceInternal -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Highly unilluminating, unfortunately.  Except you can see that it is not a special `Binomial` property that is being exploited, just a rational function.  In principle, sums with rational terms can be computed by partial fractions decomposition (over the complex numbers), using [identities](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.7#ii) like

```
Sum[1/(n - a), {n, 1, k}]
(*  -PolyGamma[0, 1 - a] + PolyGamma[0, 1 - a + k]  *)
```

to find the partial sum of each term.  Then total up the partial sums and take the limit.  (If you carry out those steps, you notice `Sum` is faster, probably because there are short-cuts, which I don't know about.)

---

The intermediate result of the method `"HypergeometricTermPFQ"` mentioned by J.M. can be obtained with:

```
Sum[1/Binomial[n, 2], {n, 2, Infinity}, Method -> "InactivePFQ"]
(*  Inactive[HypergeometricPFQ][{1, 1}, {3}, 1]  *)
```

The hypergeometric series is constructed from the ratio of successive terms as explained in [*MathWorld's* Hypergeometric Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricSeries.html).